Can lifetime be specified for AsRef impl
Is it possible to implement a trait, in this case looking at AsRef with a specific lifetime, in this case static. From playing around I think it's not possible but would like to know more detail and possible workarounds.
For example, if I had a Car enum, I can implement AsRef<str> but since these are unit enums and values are know at compile time I would like for them to be static:
enum Car {
    Ferrari,
    Fiat,
}

impl AsRef<str> for Car {
    fn as_ref(&self) -> &'static str {
        match self {
            Self::Ferrari => "ferrari",
            Self::Fiat => "fiat",
        }
    }
}

So I can change the trait fn return signature to &'static str instead of &str but I don't think it does anything, I think it's just accepted because it doesn't look at lifetimes but when the trait is called it's going to be called with the lifetime signatures of the trait itself, so no static.
And some expressions like the following:
let cars: Vec<Car> = vec![Car::Ferrari, Car::Fiat];
let names: Vec<&'static str> = cars.into_iter().map(|car| car.as_ref()).collect();

produces the following compile error:
cannot return value referencing function parameter `car` returns a value referencing data owned by the current function.
The only way around this that I found is to declare a new trait:
pub trait AsStaticRef<T>
where
    T: ?Sized,
{
    fn as_static_ref(&self) -> &'static T;
}

impl AsStaticRef<str> for Car {
    fn as_static_ref(&self) -> &'static str {
        match self {
            Self::Ferrari => "ferrari",
            Self::Fiat => "fiat",
        }
    }
}

And that works, but I don't know the internals of rust that well, so my guess is just that the trait defines those signatures with that lifetime so the way traits works it won't look into the specific implementation for other lifetime signatures, but I'm not sure, so any extra information would be great.
I have this rust playground link if helpful.

"I think it's just accepted because it doesn't look at lifetimes" -- This is wrong. It does look at lifetimes; however, lifetimes are allowed to be variant. That is, you can specify a longer lifetime, but not a shorter one. Since 'static is longer than any other lifetime, it is accepted anywhere a shorter lifetime appears.

Is there a reason you need specifically AsRef and not a custom method?

@cdhowie thanks that explains a lot of the situation

@ChayimFriedman no, i'm using this project for work as an opportunity to learn rust since other components are fairly simple so just taking step for step and seeing what exists in standard lib, but several times I've thought actually was probably not the best to use AsRef as can be ambiguous, for context using AsRef right now to go from column name enum to its sql name to execute queries.

@cdhowie idk if you care but if you put that as answer I'll accept since it does answer the underlying question about how the compiler works
